# Issues on routes and blade with dynamic variable

Tags: php, laravel-4

i have this Route code

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug) {
  return View::make('page'); 
});
```

...let say, my url `$slug` is "about" as the value, inside my `page.blade.php` will need to see this `$slug` "about" and output it as `@include('modules.page.$slug')` where the `$slug` should be the about in short, i would like to happen that my `@include` read this `$slug` as my dynamic name to call different page.

```
@section('content')
  @include('modules.page.$slug')
  @include('layouts.creic')
@stop
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should pass the $slug variable to your view like this:

```
<?php 
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug) {
    return View::make('page', array('slug' => $slug)); 
});
```

And, in your blade view... Don't use single quotes when you're using variables.

```
@include("modules.page.$slug")
```

Comment: Nice, this is neat than to my current... Many thanks for the help! Appreciate it sir @rotvulpix

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always fetch it from the Request class:

```
@section('content')
  @include('modules.page.'.Request::segment(1))
  @include('layouts.creic')
@stop
```

Alternatively, you could pass it down to the view:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug) {
  return View::make('page')->with('slug', $data); 
});
```

And access it like you already do:

```
@section('content')
  @include('modules.page.'.$slug)
  @include('layouts.creic')
@stop
```